# Can't activate Pro SNAP WordPress plugin

Tags: wordpress

Activation process after entering the activation key is lasting forever with the message "Your plugin will be automatically upgraded."

I got php7 on my server.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an error message in my php error log file: 
FastCGI sent in stderr: "*PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function utf8_decode() in ...*"

Then I've fixed it:

```
$ sudo apt-get install php7.1-xml 
$ sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
```

After that I could activate my SNAP PRO WordPress plugin.